# how to make countdown pause if the user not active in this tab and continue if active?

Tags: javascript

this is my code how can i make countdown pause if user is not active in that tab and resume again if he will open the tab

```
   var count= 10;

var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);
function timer(){
    //alert("hi");
    count=count-1;

    if (count <= 0){ 
        //alert("done");
        $('#wpblitz-wait1').css('display', 'none');
        $('#wpblitz-generate').css('display', 'block');
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    $("#wpblitz-time").html(count);
```

Comment: Please define: "user is not active". There are a variety of techniques for measuring levels of user-engagement - and they aren't all reliable.

Comment: **Tip**: Don't increment or decrement a counter in a `setInterval` or `setTimeout` callback because intervals between calls are **not** guaranteed to be exact - eventually you'll have clock-jitter. Instead always assume your timer callbacks will be invoked at varying amounts and instead simply subtract the start time from the current time to get a time-left or time-elapsed value.

Comment: how can i do that pls im just newbie @Dai

Answer (score -1):

You can use window.focus which allows to focus on the window.

Call the function only when focus is on current window.

Also the window.blur() method is used to check if user shifting focus away from the current window.

```
$(window).focus(function() 
{
    var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);
});
```

Comment: the time must pause if user is transferring to another window and continue again if user is back to the window